# Accessing session.upload_progress from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The title says it all. 
Because of the session abstraction layer of laravel I do not get how to retrive session.upload_progress in php 5.4

When I try to print $_SESSION it returns an empty array

what am i missing ?

Comment: Do you set session_start()?

Comment: i tried it by hand and it didn't change a thing ... laravel starts it automatically. I can even return the session_id.

Answer (score 0):

Well i answered my own question realizing i inverted the "value and name" values of the Form::hidden method.

BUT
i still have to set the PHP Session ID with

session_id($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]);

session_start();

before i am able to get the session content ... there must be a better way ?